# How can I manage time/date as currency in PHP?

Tags: php, date, time

I am developing an application on which the only currency that exists is time. The time is displayed in this format to the user `0000:00:0:00:00` which stands for `YYYY:WW:D:HH:MM`. 
The time should **always** be displayed in this format, so if I only had one hour the time should be displaying in this `0000:00:1:00:00`format.

**I also need methods to add/reduce/set the time.**

**What I have tried**

- Handling it as int
- Handling it as string and only editing certain digits of it.
- Using the `DateTime()` class. This worked well until I wanted to display zero time, so `0000:00:0:00:00`, which is not possible with that class.

This is driving me nuts for a week now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could use [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) instead, although not sure the best way to do it.  You could use it as the difference between a `DateTime` and a set date acting as 0.

Comment: Why not create your own class (with the proper `__toString` implementation to get that output)? Then you're free to do exactly what you want with it.

Comment: @Jeto how could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your own class that can work from your desired format and output according to it:

```
final class TimeCurrency
{
  public static function createFromString(string $formatted): self
  {
    if (!preg_match('/^(\d{4}):(\d{2}):(\d{1}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/', $formatted, $matches)) {
      throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Invalid currency format.');
    }
    return new self(...array_slice($matches, 1));
  }

  /** @var int */
  private $year;
  /** @var int */
  private $weekNumber;
  /** @var int */
  private $day;
  /** @var int */
  private $hour;
  /** @var int */
  private $minute;

  public function __construct(int $year, int $weekNumber, int $day, int $hour, int $minute)
  {
    $this->year = $year;
    $this->weekNumber = $weekNumber;
    $this->day = $day;
    $this->hour = $hour;
    $this->minute = $minute;
  }

  public function addYears(int $addedYears): void
  {
    $this->year += $addedYears;
  }

  public function __toString(): string
  {
    return sprintf('%04d:%02d:%d:%02d:%02d', $this->year, $this->weekNumber, $this->day, $this->hour, $this->minute);
  }
}

// Example usage
$currency = TimeCurrency::createFromString('2010:21:1:23:21');
$currency->addYears(4);
echo $currency;
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/cqRPE**

Obviously this is an incomplete example, because it's a bit difficult to figure out exactly what you need from your opening post, but it should at least give you the idea.

You'll probably need quite a few additional methods depending on your needs, some validity checks (e.g. minutes <= 59), etc.

Answer (score 0):

This should really be split into two separate problems within your application.

1. **Internal time management operations** - How does your system use time? Do you just add / subtract? What's the shortest unit of time you'll operate on? Is it `1 second` or will you have `sub-second` accuracy?
2. **Visual layer** - How is the time displayed to the user? You can use @Jeto's answer as guidance. This is the place where you take your *internal unit of time* and convert it to the visual value the user actually sees.

I strongly believe this separation of concerns will make your life so much easier in the future. You'll be able to easily unit test each individual component and layer.

---

You probably don't want to touch **DateTime** at all because it will start to apply the "calendar" logic to your numbers. You might suddenly end up with a leap year in your maths, which is probably not what you want.

**DateInterval** is better suited here because as the name implies, it's intended to work with intervals (which is what you want) and not physical calendar dates. However I'm worried you'll still very quickly run into unintended edge cases.

Storing your duration in **string format** is a terrible idea, because you'll have to parse it every time and still cast it down to either DateInterval or unix timestamp, over-complicating this massively.

In my head, this leaves only one contender - **integer**. Unix timestamp is the most obvious candidate here, but you might have to use microtime or something similar if you need sub-second costs.

---

Once you have your internal data format decided, you'll be able to easily construct a visual representation parser. You know, "divide seconds by 60 to get minutes", "divide by 60 to get hours", "by 24 to get days" etc etc etc, pad each result with zeros to make it double digit and you're done!

Good luck :)